# Enable binding with multiple boolean observable flags

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

Trying to bind enable state using data-bind based on two flags. We need to enable a input box if `flagA` is true and also `flagB` is false.

```js
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.flagA = ko.observable(true);
    self.flagB = ko.observable(false);
    self.changeState = function () {
        self.flagA(false);
    }
}
 
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type='text' data-bind='enable: flagA && !flagB' />
<button data-bind='click:changeState'>changeState</button>
```

Can any one help me find out why it is not working?

I've tried using a function like `enable:function(){flagA && !flagB}` to make this work. But it's not working: it does not observe when I change the state using a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `flagA` and `flagB` are observables (which are functions) you need to call them without any argument to get there values if you are using them in an expression:

```
<input type='text' data-bind='enable: flagA() && !flagB()' />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u44aous/).

Comment: Great! it works fine. you are correct about unwrapping the boolean :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid putting logic in your views, it's a bad practice. In order to do this add `computed` variable

```
self.isEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.flagA() && !this.flagB()
    }, this);
```

and bind it as usual:

```
<input type='text' data-bind='enable: isEnabled' />
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ce13d68/)